# CSS3 background image fadeIN on image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to re-create in css3 the function of the bottom 3 image hover effects on this page just as a personal project http://themes.grandpixels.com/muse/

It's done in jquery on the site I guess but as far as I know that could be possible with css3 also?

Basically I want to hover over an image and have a background image gradually fade in to view instead of the first image.

Anybody got any idea how to do this? I've been stuck literally all morning.

Thanks for the help :)

http://jsfiddle.net/r74gw/

```
 <body>

 <div class="nav">
<img url="http://imgur.com/vErJT32,DQWhz1e#0">
 </div>

 </body>

 #nav {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
 }

    #nav img {
display: block;
margin: 0 5px;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;
background: url(http://imgur.com/vErJT32,DQWhz1e#1) no-repeat center top;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
transition: background 0.5s linear;

 }


    #nav img:hover {
background: url(http://imgur.com/vErJT32,DQWhz1e#1) no-repeat center top;
background: rgba(100, 125, 175, 0);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot affect the opacity of a background image with CSS.

Comment: would it be possible to say have another background solid layer over it that fades to 0% opacity on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many mistakes here :)
`<img src="http://imgur.com/vErJT32,DQWhz1e#0" alt=""/>` and not `<img url="http://imgur.com/vErJT32,DQWhz1e#0">` attribute `url` is not valid here.

to fade `img` to show `background` can be simply done with CSS transition + opacity.

```
<div class="nav">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature">
 </div>
```

associate basic CSS:

```
.nav {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city) no-repeat;
}
.nav img {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.nav:hover img {
  opacity:0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HEwuF/

Comment: Else to animate background is possible with position , but fading requires to pile containers . these can be img, tag with background or pseudo element. it's a bit more complexe :)  example with fake fading bg http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/DJdja

Answer (score 0):

CSS is possible but using an absolutely positioned element or, in this example; a pseudo element

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/r74gw/12/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:480px;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

.nav:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/vErJT32.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .5s ease;
}


.nav:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
```

}